# How to make bottom nav background color lighter with elevation in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

In XML we have material3 bottom navigation bar style. It's color achieved by using `surface` color with `elevation = 3dp`. So in XML higher elevation means lighter background color.

I'm trying to implement same behavior in Compose. But it looks like `elevation` in Compose doesn't change bottom navigation's color but only adding shadow. So can we apply same behavior in Compose somehow or the only way is to add separate bottom nav's color in `Color.kt`?

```
BottomNavigation(
            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(80.dp),
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
            elevation = 3.dp
        )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably not using material3 library but the old one. There is no `BottomNavigation` composable in material3, it's called [`NavigationBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#navigationbar) and it has `tonalElevation` argument instead of `elevation` that does what you want.

Comment: That's true. Somehow in Material3 doc it's leading to old material in compose... Thanks